# How to get Factory Adress from Router Address?

Tags: solidity, web3js, web3.py

How to get the factory adress from the routeur please

Web3 command ?
Js ?

I know we can get it with google but how with coding ?

Comment: Uniswap's v2 routers have a `factory` getter that returns the factory.

Comment: ?? But how to get the factory from the routeur ???

Comment: If you have the router just call the factory getter. `let factory = await router.methods.factory()` using web3js.

Comment: Thanks your so much !!! I dont understand you talk about the function in 1st answer, i dont know there is a function to get factory ! Ahha thanks your so much !!! Give me your wallet adress !